# Embedding PHP with android Barcode apk

Tags: php, android, html

HTML file

```
<input type = "Text" value="" name="read_barcode" id="read_barcode" onclick = function(read_barcode)>
<input type= "Submit" value="Submit">
```

process.php

```
$value = $_post['barcode_value'];
```

Hi friends I'm going to develop a web application for android device in that if I tap the input text box the camera has to be activated for capturing the barcode after reading the bar code the value has to be forwarded to process.php . Is it possible to work in this concept or suggest me any other alternatives if possible , please explain me with source code , as i'm new to this concept .

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 3.0, you can have the camera app launch from an 'input' object like this:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
```

you can then retreive / process the image in your php file.

This route does mean that you will need to process the bar code on the server using PHP.

Comment: could you brief little bit more on this concept

Comment: Attempting to read a barcode using javascript and live camera stream will be terribly slow and cumbersome. performance will vary per device, and it will be complex to implement.
It's a lot easier to make a php script that will let you upload a photo, and then tries to find the bar code in the photo, returning the bar code value  on postback.

Comment: PHP has ready made libraries and/or PEAR packages that should be able to handle most of this for you